# In jq, how to select the desired properties at all levels?

Tags: jq

It seems a pretty basic need, but I can't find it in the tutorial

Imagine we got an object like:

```
{"data":[
  {"prop1":"a", "prop2":"b", "prop3":"c", "prop4":"d", "nestedprops":{"nestedprop1":"A","nestedprop2":"B"} },
  {"prop2":"b", "prop3":"c", "nestedprops":{"nestedprop1":"A"}},
  {"prop3":"c"}
]}
```

I just want the exact same json, but filtering out prop3,prop4 and nestedprop2,
or in other words, I want to filter in the whole tree for prop1, prop2 and nestedprop1

```
{"data":[
  {"prop1":"a", "prop2":"b", "nestedprops":{"nestedprop1":"A"} },
  {"prop2":"b", "nestedprops":{"nestedprop1":"A"}},
  {}
]}
```

I'm trying with jq '.data[] | {prop1,prop2,nestedprops:{nestedprop1}}' and the like but I can't find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just want the exact same json, but filtering out prop3,prop4 and nestedprop2

Update each item in the array by deleting what you want to be filtered out:

```bash
.data[] |= del(.prop3, .prop4, .nestedprops.nestedprop2)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/D-I2Mqjg6dl)

> I want to filter in the whole tree for prop1, prop2 and nestedprop1

Update each item by picking what you need. Filter for non-null values using `values`, and default to an empty object using `//`.

```bash
.data[] |= (pick(.prop1, .prop2, .nestedprops.nestedprop1 | values) // {})
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/j1ndjRV3YCL)

Comment: Amazing! The second shape is what i was looking for. It does not work in jq 1.6 though! Had to upgrade to 1.7. Thanks!!

Comment: @Whimusical Yes, `pick` was introduced with 1.7. For prior versions, one could copy it over from [builtin.jq](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L261C1-L264C38) where it is implemented.

Comment: @Whimusical Yet another way employing `tostream` and `setpath` that also works with jq 1.6: `.data[] |= reduce (tostream | select(IN(.[-2]; ["prop1"], ["prop2"], ["nestedprops", "nestedprop1"]))) as [$p,$v] ({}; setpath($p;$v))` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/28GGwbmjxM-) (replace `IN` using [builtin.jq](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/blob/c95b34ff827d05a2d262f00280a4891a295ed0ed/src/builtin.jq#L280) to make it compatible with 1.5)

Answer (score 1):

To omit specific keys at all levels, you could use `walk`, e.g.

```
walk(if type == "object" then del(.prop3, .prop4, .nestedprop2) end)
```

The above presupposes your jq allows `if ... then ... end`; if not, add the `else .` clause.

---

To keep selected keys recursively in this case is perhaps a bit trickier and depends on the specific requirements.  Here's one approach:

```
def keep:
  if type == "object"
  then if has("prop1") or has("prop2") or has("nestedprops")
       then {prop1, prop2, nestedprops} | with_entries( if .value == null then empty end)
       elif has("nestedprop1") then {nestedprop1}
       else {}
       end
  else .
  end;

.data |= walk(keep)
```